# How compile without canopy a package which expects to have canopy installed?

Tags: python-2.7, canopy

I am using virtualbox with guess-Windows 8 and host linux-ubuntu-16.04. 
In Linux, with standard python 2.7 I am trying to compile this program:

https://github.com/henryroe/xenics_pluto

which says:
"This version of xenics software expects a copy of Enthought's Canopy python installation to be installed and available as the default python (or at least be the default python in the terminal session from which you want to run xenics.)"

I am not authorized to install canopy in mi computer. As I do not have canopy, I can not compile this. This is the error:

```
g++ -c -fPIC -O -ansi -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D_DEBUG -g3 xenics_wrap.cpp -o xenics_wrap.o -I/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7/ -I/Users/s/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/
xenics_wrap.cpp:154:21: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The question is: Is there any way to compile this "canopy-designed" program in standard python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, by default, Canopy installs entirely into your personal user profile (mostly into `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, with config info in `%APPDATA%`), so you should not need admin rights to do so, especially if you respond "no" to the post-install question "Make Canopy be my default Python?" You can then meet xenic's "default python" requirement by opening a Canopy Command Prompt from Canopy's Tools menu.

OTOH, it's possible that your guest account is so constrained that you can't even run executables that are in your profile. If that's the case, then you won't even be able to run the installer, much less run Canopy in your profile.